# How can I update array in array Firestore swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Please I'm unable to find a good example to update subscribers in categories here as the model below.

```
struct Categories: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
   var id : String?
   var categories : [Category]?  
}

struct Category : Identifiable, Codable, Hashable{
   var id :String
   var category_id: String?
   var icon : String?
   var textColor :String?
   var backgroundColor :String?
   var language : CategoryLanguage?
   var subscribers: [String]? // <--- I want to add/remove/update the subscribers, which may or may not be in a specific index.

}
```

I tried :

```
    let docData: [String: Any] = [
                     "categories": [
                        "category_id": topicName,
                        "subscriber": [
                            subscribers
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
```

Is that okay or do I have to add anything else? and How can I add subscribers in specific indexes in the array?

I have a list of categories, each category has subscribers, I need to add/remove/update the subscribers in a specific category.
Thanks

Comment: In addition, did you see the documentation on adding an item to an array with `FieldValue.arrayUnion`? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#swift_12

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your comment,
I updated the code.
I tried to use arrayUnion but I'm not sure how can add a new item in array of array

Comment: @AlamaYasein how? just follow the documentation of `.update(FieldValue.arrayUnion())`, they give you an example of how to use it.

Comment: Hi @Stoic
I tried different solutions to figure out my issue,I even get empty array, or duplicate 
I added a comment in the module.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in `firebase` there are 2 way to perform things.

1. using `FireStore`

   import FirebaseFirestore

**Update**

```
    func updateCategory(_ category: Category) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        do {
            try db.collection("categories").document("subscriber").setData(from: category. subscribers) // arr of subscriber 
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

**Delete**

```
    func deleteCategory(_ category: Category) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("categories").document(category.subscribers[i]).delete()
    }
```

**Note:** Make sure while call updated function your `subscribers` should be updated

2. using `Database`

   import FirebaseDatabase

**Update**

```
    func updateCategory(_ arrOfDict:[[String:Any]]) { 
        Database.database(url: url).reference().child("categories").setValue(arrOfDict) { // url might be database url
            (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Data could not be update: \(error).")
            } else {
                print("Data updated successfully!")
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**

```
func deleteCategory(subscriberId:String){
    let ref = Database.database(url: url).reference().child("categories")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {snapshot in
        if var categories = snapshot.value as? [[String: Any]]{
            var positionToRemove = 0
            for category in categories{
                if let arrOfSubscriber = category["subscriber"] as? [String]{
                    for id in arrOfSubscriber {
                       if id == subscriberId {
                         break
                       }
                       positionToRemove += 1
                    }
                }
            }
            
            categories.remove(at: positionToRemove)
            ref.setValue(categories, withCompletionBlock: { error, _ in
                guard error == nil else {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                print("deleted subscriber")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jatin,
Thanks for your reply, I appreciate that very much.
I want to explain to you more what the exact problem is,
I have a list of categories, each category has subscribers, I need to add/remove/update the subscribers in a specific category.

Comment: @AlamaYasein then just change the document path to your desired document and category... Please read the documentation! it explains all of this :)

Comment: @AlamaYasein than in logic you need to check for categories ids than it will work. as per Stoic & Frank van Puffelen comment you need to read document it will guide you properly